# Arduino solenoid project is not working

Tags: arduino

I am trying to control a [solenoid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid) using an [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno). I followed instructions described in the tutorial *[Controlling solenoids with Arduino](http://www.instructables.com/id/Controlling-solenoids-with-arduino/?ALLSTEPS)*.

The solenoids are [Solenoid - 5 V (small)](http://store.mansteri.com/index.php/en/motors-actuators/solenoid-5v-small.html) and [Solenoid 36 V](http://store.mansteri.com/index.php/en/motors-actuators/solenoid-36-v.html). The resistor is 10 kohm, transistor is [IRF520](http://www.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets_pdf/I/R/F/5/IRF520.shtml), the diode is [1N4007](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1N4001_and_1N5400_series_diodes), and the DC battery voltage has been measured to be 7.45 V.

When I connect a small solenoid, it vibrates 3 or 4 times normally and its arm is just kind of jammed at a position and start vibrating (kind of trembling) with a high frequency. If I use a big solenoid, it vibrates 3 or 4 times and then stops.

Here is my code:

```
int solPin = 13;

void setup() {                
    pinMode(solPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(solPin, HIGH);
    delay(100);               
    digitalWrite(solPin, LOW);
    delay(100);               
}
```

Where is the problem and how can it be fixed?

Comment: It is possible the power demands, spikes, etc of the solenoid are resetting your processor.  Try putting some serial logging in your setup() function and and maybe log a running count in your loop() and then open the serial monitor to watch the resulting messages.  At the least that will help you decide if you have a *software* problem or a *hardware* one.

Comment: OK, it start working. I put some log statement & it start wirking. It's working even after removing log statement :)
Thank you for you reply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arduino solenoid project behaves strangely when operated on PC power supply](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16693205/arduino-solenoid-project-behaves-strangely-when-operated-on-pc-power-supply)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[delay(int x)](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Delay) where x in milli seconds. So you have it delaying for 1/10 of a second?

Your [MOSFET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOSFET) transistor is very large, but that is good as long as the Arduino can supply the current to keep it open. You should write a print statement that prints a number, something like

```
 Serial.println(count);
 count = count +1;
```

If this number keeps resetting (not from overflow) then you know your power system has problems.

PS: don't forget

```
   Serial.begin(9600);
```

Voltage issue

The image shows 2 9 volts in series, so 18 volts. I don't know what the minimun voltage required is, but this could be important.

Comment: OK, it start working. I put some log statement & it start wirking. It's working even after removing log statement :)
Thank you for you reply

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be working correctly per your code; Your code will produce a 5hZ output signal. I could not find your schematic so I am short on a lot of details. The solenoid should not be powered from the Arduino. The arduino is not a power supply. Try increasing each delay to 1000, you should then be cycling at a 0.5hZ rate.